# JavaScript id + class vs. class selector performance

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm wondering what is faster to select a class of elements that reside inside an element with ID. For example let's say we have a list, `ul` with `id="list"` and `li` elements with `class="list"`, then which is faster (and/or better practice):

```
document.GetElementById('list').getElementsByClassName('list')
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName('list')
```

I am aware that the former will target only elements inside `#list` elements, let's assume that the class is unique to the whole document.

Comment: The first is most likely faster for some browsers but there's only one way to know: profile it.

Comment: This question is not primarily opinion-based as the test makes it fact based.

Answer (score 3):

getElementsByClassName is an O(n) operation because it must inspect every element to check for the existence of the class name being examined. If the `n` is limited, then the speed will increase, however the difference in speed will only be minor as the overall speed of the operation will still be O(n).

As a result, this is an example of a micro-optimization. Neither is significantly faster. Using sub selectors should be related to page composition in order to differentiate styling parts of the page with regards to speed considerations.

Comment: It's probably wise to code as if `getElementsByClassName` is *O(n)*, but browsers may keep internal data structures that effectively amortizes that cost out over individual DOM initialization and updates.

Comment: @Pointy - You think that the browser has an internal cache of elements by class name which is populated on page load and live updated as the page is modified? Do you have a link to any material that describes such a process or approach? I know that chrome's engine aggressively seeks to improve performance but I have never heard of class names being used behind the scenes.

Comment: Well even though people say "the DOM is slow", modern browsers handle doing stuff like adding/removing a class from a parent element causing lots of implied-by-CSS updates *really* quickly. I'm not a browser implementor, but in a world with huge CSS rule sets and large DOMs, they've got to be doing *something*. I admit however that I'm just making a semi-educated guess.

Comment: I guess I should not bother with it. I did a test in my application, the first one is faster, but it's really insignificant.

Answer (score 0):

The first should be the fastest as the retrieval of elements by class name will be constrained to that list element. However, it depends on how the browser indexes the elements internally.

You can run some benchmarks here: http://jsperf.com/javascript-select-by-id-vs-by-class

In my tests, the second approach was faster on chrome and IE, but roughly the same on FF. What this means is that Chrome and IE index elements based off class name and FF mostly doesn't or does a poor job at it.